# How can I alter the case of a merge field in email templates?

Tags: email-template

I have email templates whose merge field values are formatted in the "Proper" case for email subjects and the like. In order to make the body of my email messages be properly formatted I would like to use the same merge field yet format its value to lowercase.

RSVP__c is a custom picklist fields in a custom object and I've tried these to no avail (both result in the merge field values missing in the email):

1. `{!LOWER(ClassEnrollment__c.RSVP__c)}`
2. `{!LOWER(TEXT(ClassEnrollment__c.RSVP__c))}`

How can this be done in the email template (i.e. without a workaround that copies a lowercase version of the field value to another field)?

Comment: I've been playing with the option to create a new field with a lowercase value of RSVP__c and am having trouble getting it to work because RSVP__c is a picklist. I'd appreciate thoughts on this option, too.

Comment: so other fields from Class_Enrollment__c worked fine?

Comment: This actually does not work on other custom fields. I added that detail b/c another post seemed to indicate the formatting functions only work with standard objects.

Comment: This does appear to work on fields in the Contact object, e.g. `{!UPPER(Contact.FirstName)}` results in MICHAEL.

Comment: Does the problem occur with `{!LOWER(ClassEnrollment__c.RSVP__c)}` or with `{!ClassEnrollment__c.RSVP__c}` too? I mean, are the values not visible when you try to conver them to lower case or they are not visible at all ?

Comment: My custom object merge field `{!LOWER(ClassEnrollment__c.RSVP__c)}` only disappears when I try and convert it. It shows up properly without the modifier (UPPER, LOWER, etc.).